# apache ant runs properly but ask me for some other things also

Tags: ant

When I use Apache-Ant following :

```
ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
```

However, it works properly but why it shows this and how can I resolve this?

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\tools.jar

Comment: Sagar, have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you have installed JRE while it is required to install JDK.

Please refer *[System Requirements of Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)*

> For the current version of Ant, you will also need a JDK installed on your system, version 1.4 or later required, 1.7 or later strongly recommended. The more up-to-date the version of Java , the more Ant tasks you get.
>
> **Note:** If a JDK is not present, only the JRE runtime, then many tasks will not work.

So, install JDK and

- set `JAVA_HOME` correctly
- add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH`